# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM

Tags: mysql, sql

I get this error at this code:

```
 SELECT "LastUpdate" ;
 FROM "xx_yy";
```

Is LastUpdate a reserved word ?

I tried to change " " to `` or delete them, I don't really know the perfect combination to make it work. I'm beginner in this.

Comment: I've got to remember that duplicate question for the future.

Comment: @user3691628 The question I linked frames this in context of PHP. Just be sure you are removing the outer quotes that make the answer examples into PHP strings if you're working directly in a MySQL client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon (`;`) signifies the end of a statement. So you actually have two separate, distinct statements:

1. `SELECT "LastUpdate"`
2. `FROM xx_yy`

The second statement is not valid, which is why you are seeing the error.

Solution: Remove the semicolon at the end of the first line:

```
SELECT "LastUpdate"
FROM "xx_yy";
```

---

Also note if the [`ANSI_QUOTES` sqlmode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) is not enabled, MySQL treats double-quotes as *string literals* (the same as single quotes). You may need to change these to the MySQL-specific backtick, or remove them entirely:

```
SELECT `LastUpdate`
FROM `xx_yy`;
```

Comment: I tried and the code work. But what you think is this error about ? Sql query failed due to [Unknown column 'LastUpdate' in 'field list'], Query: [SELECT LastUpdate FROM xx_yy;]

Comment: It could have to do with quoting. In MySQL, if the table was created with quoted column names that are not all-caps, you will have to always select with quoted column and it is CASE-SENSITIVE.

Comment: I don't know, the names are same the same, I really have no ideea how to solve it. I'll be so thankfull if you can help me. I'd like to know if you need more informations, I can send you a PM with some screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the quotes around your column identifier and tablename. That makes them strings instead of identifiers. Either use ticks or nothing at all. Also, ditch the semi-colon after the first line as it is terminating your query before it reaches the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT `LastUpdate` 
 FROM `xx_yy`;
```

or

```
SELECT LastUpdate 
 FROM xx_yy;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first semicolon.

`SELECT FOO FROM BAR`

The above is all one statement.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your query should look like

```
SELECT "LastUpdate" FROM "xx_yy";
```

; is marking an end of a query.